# Can't displaying combo box list

Tags: combobox, show, display

I have a problem with a combo box, I can't display the data inside the combo, I have to do right click before a left click to show my data, but with a just a left click its not possible.

The below image show the first case(when I do a left click)

[image: The below image show the first case(when I do a left click)].

The below image show the second case(when I do a right click before the left click)
[image: this image show the second case(when I do a right click before the left click)]

Thanks for help

Comment: You should add more information so we can help you debug, like a piece of code, the function you are using for handling the clicks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
* Configure the renderer appropriately with the status of the
* Drawing object.
*/
```

public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list,
                                                  Object value,
                                                  int index,
                                                  boolean isSelected,
                                                  boolean cellHasFocus ) {
       Component theResult = super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus );
       System.out.println("theResult : "+theResult.toString());
       System.out.println("déb methode getLi class AWICombo => value "+value+" ,index "+index+" ,isSelected "+isSelected+",celhasFocus "+cellHasFocus);
       // display crash in combo box with jdk 1.3 : setOpaque(true) solves the problem.
       //( (JComponent) theResult ).setOpaque( true );
       //setOpaque( true );
       if ( index == -1 ) {
           System.out.println("In if index == -1");
           return theResult;
       }
       try {
           System.out.println("In try bloc 1");
           boolean notEmpty = false;
           AWCState theObjectToDisplay = null;

```
       try {
           System.out.println("In try bloc 2");
           System.out.println("index " +index);
           System.out.println("theModel call :" +theModel.toString());
           theObjectToDisplay = (AWCState) theModel.theComboValues.elementAt( index );
           System.out.println("theObjectToDisplay => "+theObjectToDisplay.toString());
           System.out.println("dans conbobox "+index);
       } catch ( java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe ) {
        aioobe.printStackTrace();
       }
       // test if the first square of the conbo box is empty for doen't set the tool tips
       if ( theObjectToDisplay != null ) {
           System.out.println("In if 1");
           if ( theObjectToDisplay.toString() != null ) {
               System.out.println("In if 2");
               if ( value.toString().compareTo( theObjectToDisplay.toString() ) != 0 ) {
                   System.out.println("In if 3");
                   if ( value.toString().compareTo( "" ) != 0 ) {
                       System.out.println("In if 4");
                       theObjectToDisplay = (AWCState) theModel.theComboValues.elementAt( index - 1 );
                       notEmpty = true;
                   }
               } else {
                   System.out.println("In else 1");
                   notEmpty = true;
               }
           }
       } else {
           System.out.println("In else 2");
           theObjectToDisplay = (AWCState) theModel.theComboValues.elementAt( index - 1 );
           notEmpty = true;
       }

       if ( isSelected ) {
           System.out.println("In if isSelected "+list.getSelectionBackground());
           System.out.println("In if isSelected "+list.getSelectionForeground());
           setBackground( list.getSelectionBackground() );
           setForeground( list.getSelectionForeground() );
           setToolTip( list, notEmpty, theObjectToDisplay, value );
       } else {
           setBackground( list.getBackground() );
           setForeground( list.getForeground() );
       }

       setFont( list.getFont() );
       if ( value == null ) {
           System.out.println("In if value == null");
        setText("");
       }
       else {
        setText(value.toString());
       }

       // object is not obsolete
       if ( theObjectToDisplay == null || theObjectToDisplay.getStatus().equals( AWCConstants.OFFICIAL ) ) {
           System.out.println("object is not obsolete theObjectToDisplay=>"+theObjectToDisplay.toString());
           return theResult;
       }



       // object is obsolete
       if ( index == 1 ) {
           return theResult;
       }
       if ( !isSelected ) {
           theResult.setBackground( Color.red );
       } else {
           theResult.setBackground( new Color( 155, 100, 155 ) );
       }

   } 
   catch ( NullPointerException npe ) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
   } 
   catch ( java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe ) {
        aioobe.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println("end of function");
   return theResult;
```

}